# UFT API REST: How can I download file in get request

Tags: rest, api, automation, hp-uft

when execute api rest with get method, the response body is a binary pdf file and I need download the ResponseHeader_Content-Disposition or file content to compare files.

It´s possible with UFT 14.51 with vbs?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For UFT API Tests you can use the Programming Languages C# and Java and a Waste Library / Platform they bring with themselves, so why not rephrase the question: How do I download a File from an HTTP Respone with Java / C#.

Afterwards implement the download Step as a Custom Activity:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/z_Ch_API_TS_Extensibility.htm

Comment: any example please?